# Cannot redirect to different pages after Login with Spring Security

Tags: java, authentication, spring-security

I'm using Spring Security for logging in to my application and I'm trying to redirect to some pages after logging in but I'm unable, I think it's a problem with my `spring-security.xml`, this is my code:

**MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler**:

```
public class MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {
  ...
  @Override
  public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
    ...
    // check if user is active after successfully logging in
    if (!isActiveStatus(authentication)) {
      logger.info("User [" + username + "] is not longer active.");
      authentication.setAuthenticated(false);
      response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/home/welcome?notactive");
      return;
    }
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

**spring-security.xml**:

```
....
<security:intercept-url pattern="/home/**" access="permitAll" />
<security:intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" />
<security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
<security:form-login login-page="/home/welcome?login"
  default-target-url="/home/welcome"
  authentication-success-handler-ref="MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler"
  authentication-failure-handler-ref="MyAuthenticationFailureHandler" />
....
```

With this code, the application always redirect to `/home/welcome?login` and never to `/home/welcome?notactive`. Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My immediate thought is that 'isActiveStatus' is returning true, so not going into that if block.

Comment: @MartinByers I assure you it's returning false, I wish that was the problem

Comment: @Alavaros: Yes, now it should work. If it is not working, please add the Spring Security log with `DEBUG`enabled (in your log configuration) to your question. It will show more details.  Do you use Spring Boot?

Comment: @dur the line `<security:intercept-url pattern="/home/**" access="permitAll" />` was already in spring-security.xml and it doesn't work, and `permitAll()`, as far as I know, it's only for Java configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be trying to manually send a redirect, the SuccessHandler has it's own mechanism for this:

```
        getRedirectStrategy().sendRedirect(request, response, "/home/welcome?notactive");
```

Comment: I'd have to extend `SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler`, but I also tested it and it doesn't work either.

Comment: Have you debugged your code to see if the code executes?

Comment: what happens if you change your redirect URL to "/home/other?notactive"?